# "Continuer de faire" ou "Continuer à faire"

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, à, de

Existe-il une règle spécifique incitant à utiliser la préposition "*de*" plutôt que "*à*" - et inversement - dans le fait d'exprimer que l'on *continue quelque chose* ?

Par exemple, quelle règle indique que dire

> Je continue **de** faire la vaisselle.

est plus correct que de dire

> Je continue **à** faire la vaisselle.

Dans ce cas, est-ce grammaticalement faux d'utiliser la préposition "*à*" ?

Comment: Pourquoi vouloir absolument qu'il y ait une règle tranchante ou une explication univoque des deux emplois ??? Et la liberté d'expression, la plasticité de la langue, son évolution spontanée et naturelle ? Dit-on à ou de en Afrique ? Au Québec ? En Louisiane ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Selon le Robert, lorsque *continuer* est suivi par un verbe à l'infinitif, *à* et *de* sont interchangeables sans indication particulière :

> Continuer *à* parler, continuer *de* parler.

Certains usages ou expressions semblent préférer l'un ou l'autre, mais sans indication précise, cependant l'emploi de *de* semble l'emporter actuellement dans l'hexagone :

> Continue *de* boire comme ça et tu vas voir !
>
> Continuer *de* travailler semble une bonne solution.

mais le *à* serait tout à fait correct à la place du *de*.

Pour l'Académie française, le *de* serait plus littéraire, plus soutenu :

> *Continuer à* ou, litt., *continuer de*, suivi de l'infinitif : persister à, ne pas cesser de. 
> «Il faut continuer à travailler. La pluie continuait de tomber. Le mal continuait de se répandre.»

Il semble que l'oreille dicte le choix de *à* ou de *de* lorsque l'équilibre sonore de la phrase peut être dissonant avec l'un des deux, ou que l'usage de l'un des deux prédomine dans certaines expressions.

---

Suite à la discussion avec Stéphane sur *[Cosette](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette)* une suggestion selon le début de l'action :

- *Continuer à* quand il s'agit d'une action commencée et que l'on continue.
- *Continuer de* quand il s'agit d'une action qu'on a l'habitude de faire.

> Cet homme, tenant son verre, continue à boire.

c'est-à-dire il achève ce qu'il avait commencé.

> Cet homme est un ivrogne, et, malgré ses promesses, il continue de boire.

c'est-à-dire il persiste dans ses habitudes d'ivrognerie.

*Cette remarque est très suggestive et ne peut servir  de règle.*

Comment: Grevisse confirme en disant mettant *commencer* dans les verbes qui « construisent l’infinitif complément avec *à* ou *de* indifféremment : c'est l'oreille qui décide. » (« Commencer par » est classé à part car il a un sens différemment).

Comment: A propos de *l'emploi de « de » semble l'emporter actuellement dans l'hexagone*: Même s'il y a un certain regain de popularité de *commencer de* depuis quelques dizaines d'années, *commencer à* l'emporte toujours largement dans les écrits, et certainement encore beaucoup plus à l'oral. https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31344/1109

Answer (score 2):

les explications données restent trop vagues, alors que la distinction repose sur une différence qu'on peut expliquer, et pas seulement par un argument de "choix libre à l'oreille" : quand on emploie "de" on est a priori sur une notion d'état
 alors que pour "à" on est dans un contexte d'action, d'où la distinction possible. Il y aurait donc une notion de durée avec "de" et une priorité sur le court terme avec "à" me semble-t-il. Par exemple "il continue de croire aux fantômes" et "il continua à parler".

Answer (score 1):

Quoique l'extrait de p 177 ne paraisse expliquer que  « commencer » , remarquer son dernier paragraphe (où j'ai mis en gras une phrase qui prétend sa pertinence à « continuer »).

<sub>Source:  *French prepositions à and de
in infinitival complements, 
A pragma-semantic analysis* (2008) by Lidia Fraczak, as part of *Adpositions ; Pragmatic, semantic and syntactic perspectives*  (2008) edited by D Kurzon, S Adler</sub>

[p 177:]  We will finish our critique of the presupposition criterion and of its relevance
to a contrastive analysis of the prepositions à and de by reconsidering the verb
*commencer* (“to start”), which can combine with either one or the other preposition
(even though *à* is more frequent). Following the ideas of Adamczewski
(1991) and of Trubert-Ouvrard (1997), it should be considered that *commencer*
is “presupposing” when accompanied by de and “non presupposing” when accompanied
by à. Trubert-Ouvrard uses, among others, the following example,
containing commencer à, to show that the preposition à is responsible for the
“rhematic status” of V2 or, in other words, its status as “a new element in the utterance”:

(10) Jean avait décidé d’aller admirer la ville depuis les hauteurs de la campagne
avoisinante; il choisit la Côte de Saint Germain pour sa première sortie et le
dimanche suivant, à l’aube, il commença à escalader la colline à partir de la
source.
‘Jean had decided to go and admire the town from the heights of the nearby
countryside; he chose the Hill of Saint Germain for his first outing, and
the following Sunday, at dawn, he began to climb the hill starting from the
source.’

It seems, on the contrary, that in spite of the presence of the preposition à, a
presupposition exists concerning the content of the complement (escalader la colline
– “to climb the hill”), due to the preceding context in which the narrator
mentions les hauteurs (“the heights”) and la Côte (“the Hill”) as well as the intention
of the protagonist to go there. The verb commencer (“to start”) carries this presupposition. Thus, the verb commencer has a presupposing nature, which is
independent of the preposition that accompanies it, **as it is also the case for the
verbs *continuer* (“to continue”)** and finir (“to finish”): we refer with these verbs to
the beginning, to the continuation or to the end of a process where the process is
presupposed.
  We can conclude from this part of the analysis that the use of the preposition
de, as opposed to à, cannot be systematically associated with the factor of situational
presupposition.

[pp 179-180:]   A comparison of the expressions continuer à and continuer de (“to continue”)
can illustrate the compatibility of the preposition de with “monovalent vision”
and the compatibility of the preposition à with “ambivalent vision” of a fact.
Thus, the preposition de should be preferred with continuer when the positive (
presupposed) version of the process expressed by the complement is strongly
privileged. This is the case in the example used by Adamczewski which we quoted
in Section 1 and which we use again here:

(11) Pas de changement dans les jours à venir. Il va continuer de faire beau jusqu’à
la fin de la semaine.
‘No change for the next few days. The weather will continue to be nice till
the end of the week.’

There is no reason in this case, from the speaker’s point of view, to question the
presupposed characteristics of the weather, or to envisage a different evolution.
We can imagine another way of viewing the same kind of information:

(12) Bonne nouvelle ! Il va continuer à faire beau jusqu’à la fin de la semaine.
‘Good news! The weather will continue to be nice till the end of the week.’

In example (12), “ambivalent vision” is adopted: the speaker communicates having
considered both the continuation of the nice weather and the contrary possibility,
even though the positive version only is asserted.
  Presenting a fact in an ambivalent way can help to build up an argumentative/
polemic value of an utterance. According to the definition given by Adam
(2002), an argumentative discourse is always placed in relation to a “counter-discourse”. Presenting a fact in an ambivalent way can help to build up an argumentative/
polemic value of an utterance. According to the definition given by Adam
(2002), an argumentative discourse is always placed in relation to a “counter-discourse”.<sup>9</sup>
We noticed, while analyzing examples from the Internet, an interesting
correlation between the use of continuer à and the structures carrying a polemic
attitude, where the speaker expresses an opinion against some situation or point
of view. Thus, we observed, for example, that continuer à is clearly preferred to
continuer de after negative expressions such as ne doit pas or ne devrait pas (“must
not” or “should not”) as well as in interrogative sentences starting with pourquoi
(“why”),<sup>10</sup> like in the examples below: [...]