# Commencer/Continuer à/de

Tags: prépositions, constructions, de, à

De nos jours on distingue

> Je commence/continue à lire.

et, respectivement

> Je commence/continue de lire.

?

Le choix entre *à* et *de* se base-t-il sur l'euphonie ? Ou la distinction décrite [ici](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/commencer-continuer-a-de-a5048120) est-elle toujours valable et enseignée à l'école ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Je commence de lire* est très rare en français littéraire, en encore plus en français parlé. *Je commence à lire* est quasiment toujours utilisé aujourd'hui.

*Je continue de lire* est assez courant en français littéraire, mais moins que *je continue à lire*. Les deux peuvent s'entendre à l'oral (pléonasme...).

Les tendances et usages respectifs de *commencer à/de* et *continuer à/de* dans les documents écrits confirment que la situation n'est pas la même pour ces deux verbes.

[image]

*Commencer de* est en perte de vitesse depuis plus de 1840 environ (passé de 5 fois moins courant à 22 fois moins courant en 2008) alors que *continuer de* est revenu un peu à la mode à partir des années 1960 qui a vu la tendance s'inverser (de 10 fois moins courant en 1960 à 6 fois moins courant en 2008).

En conclusion, je recommanderais à quelqu'un qui apprend le français de n'utiliser que *à* avec *commencer* et privilégier aussi *à* avec *continuer* car il ne surprend jamais quel que soit le registre.